# Why would android studio debug buttons stay disabled after it hits a breakpoint?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

Can someone explain to me why android studio would hit a breakpoint(the red has > in the middle) but the buttons like step-in step-out... stay disabled and there is no way to get the values of the variables on the line and before the line where the breakpoint is set? Here is a snippet of my recent code. The breakpoint was at the last line of this method, ma.regid=text;

```
public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.mypackage.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";
        public MapActivity ma;

        public ResponseReceiver(){}

        public ResponseReceiver(MapActivity act){
        this.ma = act;
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String text = intent.getStringExtra(RegistrationIntentService.PARAM_OUT) ;
            ma.regid = text;
            //intent.getStringExtra(RegistrationIntentService.PARAM_OUT);
        }
    }
```

This is not the first time I run into this issue.

Comment: Question is too vague. Post code where break point is set, and EXACT way to reproduce. Images are a plus.

Comment: I have added a snippet now. I have updated the question.